# What is included in NGX Bootstrap(Nav bar, pills and such)? What modules do I have to call / include to use (BSDropdown0=)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, types, angular-cli

I have recently started using Angular CLI to start a simple application. I have just included NGX-Bootstrap, which is just the updated version of ng2-bootstrap. I saw that to use alerts and the drop down, I have to import the module. My question is what modules are built in still and which ones I will have to import. I know the documentation is here: http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/ 
But for the nav bar is it still built in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar.

NGX-Bootstrap provides you some pre-built component built for Angular, based on Bootstrap CSS and JS.
But Bootstrap is still there, so you can still reference to the Bootstrap Api.

If you are using Bootstrap 4.0.alpha you need to watch here:
[Bootstrap4-alpha - API NAVBAR](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

Comment: I guess I just didn't understand what NGX-Bootstrap really is. This makes more sense, I am also using BS4. Thank you.